# Codeigniter omit spaces in active record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to call my codeigniter active record like this :

```
function updateParticipant($data){
    $final_data = array(
        'order' => $data['order'],
    );
    $this->db->set($final_data);
    $this->db->where('type_participant', $data['type_participant']);
    $this->db->where('order', $data['prev_order']);
    $this->db->where('challenge_id', $data['challenge_id']);
    $this->db->update('mainchallenge mc JOIN participant p on mc.id_participant = p.id_participant');
}
```

it will produce like this :

> UPDATE mainchallenge mc JOIN participant p on mc.id_participant =
>   p.id_participant SET `order` = **0WHERE** `type_participant` = **'1'AND**
>   `order` = **'1'AND** `challenge_id` = '3'

As you can see, there is no white-space between 0 and where, also in '1'AND that leads me to syntax error. How can I overcome this ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Give space in `where` condition

```
function updateParticipant($data){
$final_data = array(
    'order' => $data['order'],
);
$this->db->set($final_data);
$this->db->where(' type_participant ', $data['type_participant']);
$this->db->where(' order ', $data['prev_order']);
$this->db->where(' challenge_i d ', $data['challenge_id']);
$this->db->update(' mainchallenge mc JOIN participant p on mc.id_participant = p.id_participant ');
```

}

*or you can use this solution*

In the database configuration file (./application/config/database.php) add a new element to array with default settings.

```
$db['default']['_protect_identifiers']= FALSE;
```

Comment: are you pretty sure on this ? did you test this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the spacing but use an active record join to make it more readable.

```
function updateParticipant($data){
    $final_data = array(
        'order' => $data['order'],
    );
    $this->db->set($final_data);
    $this->db->where('type_participant', $data['type_participant']);
    $this->db->where('order', $data['prev_order']);
    $this->db->where('challenge_id', $data['challenge_id']);
    $this->db->join('participant p', 'mc.id_participant = p.id_participant');
    $this->db->update('mainchallenge mc');
}
```

try outputting the result with this

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

I'm surprised of any spacing issues, outputting the last query as it was built will show if the spacing is incorrect from CI or if you have another syntax error...

Answer (score -1):

Set the variable as string.  Replace $data['order'] to  "$data[order]" . It should work.

```
 $final_data = array(
            'order' => "$data[order]",
        );
```

Comment: try it and see you will figure it out.